# Badge Statistics and maximum number of badges on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, data-explorer

We can see statistics about reputation at https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow.

How can I find who had maximum number of badges on Stack Overflow ? It would be nice to see extracted from data center.

I would like to see all maximum statistics of badges:

- Person having maximum total no. of badges
- Person having maximum general badges
- Person having maximum no. of tag badges
- Person having maximum bronze badges
- Person having maximum silver badges
- Person having maximum gold badges
- Person having maximum general bronze badges
- Person having maximum general silver badges
- Person having maximum general gold badges
- Person having maximum tag bronze badges
- Person having maximum tag silver badges
- Person having maximum tag gold badges

Solution to all questions might be [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). But I want to a foolproof solution for this

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: [Users by Number of General Gold Badges](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69181/users-by-number-of-gold-non-tag-badges). There's no way to tell if a badge is gold, so you need to hard-core the list of badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Top Tag Badge Counts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65676/top-tag-badge-counts)

```
Select Top 10 UserId As [User Link],
    Count(*) As NumTagBadges
From Badges
Where Name In (Select TagName from Tags Where IsNull(TagName,'')<>'')
Group By UserId
Order By NumTagBadges Desc
```

Top 4:

1. Jon Skeet - 387
2. Marc Gravell - 157
3. Darin Dimitrov - 132
4. BalusC - 116

[Top Gold, Silver and Bronze Tag Badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65774/compare-gold-silver-and-bronze-tag-badges)

<sup>SQL too complex</sup>

Top 4 Gold:

1. Jon Skeet - 25
2. Marc Gravell - 11
3. Darin Dimitrov - 10
4. BalusC - 10

Top 4 Silver:

1. Jon Skeet - 76
2. Marc Gravell - 29
3. SLaks - 27
4. BalusC - 22

Top 4 Bronze:

1. Jon Skeet - 286
2. Marc Gravell - 117
3. Darin Dimitrov - 101
4. BalusC - 84

[Top Non-Tag Badge Counts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65677/top-non-tag-badge-counts)

```
Select Top 10 UserId As [User Link],
   Count(*) As NumNonTagBadges
From Badges
Where Name Not In (Select TagName from Tags)
 And IsNull(Name,'')<>''
Group By UserId
Order By NumNonTagBadges Desc
```

Top 4:

1. Jon Skeet - 4581
2. Marc Gravell - 1497
3. Eric Lippert - 1164
4. JaredPar - 935

Comment: I have no idea if the removal of `Null` and `''` is needed.

Comment: I [have](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65678/generate-no-empty-tagnames-in-any-existing-database) [confirmed](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65679/no-empty-tagnames-in-any-existing-database) the `Null` and `''` check was not needed.

Comment: Nice work. Is it possible to get maximum counts with 3 different types also?

Comment: [This (should*)](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65774/compare-gold-silver-bronze-tag-badges) compares Gold, Silver and Bronze Tag Badges, based on the fact that the first one is Bronze, a second is Silver and a third is Gold. The non-Tag badges would need to be manually listed in `IN ('','',...)` clauses to get them. (*) I assume the data is being updated at the moment, which is why the current results don't make sense.

Comment: I've created [Data Explorer Discussions](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/495/data-explorer-discussions) in chat to determine what is actually wrong with the Gold, Silver, Bronze query.

Comment: Tim Stone [rewrote](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68615/gold-silver-and-bronze-tag-badges) my query without Unions.

Comment: My [Gold, Silver and Bronze Tag Badges query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65774/compare-gold-silver-and-bronze-tag-badges) now works as expected. Clearly the Select Top Union Order By does do something different to what is expected.

Comment: And, in fact, my query correctly includes the Gold badges in Silver and Bronze counts, etc. Changing the answer now...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks The Establishment,

For Maximum number of badges (all kinds)-

```
SELECT TOP 100
    Users.Id as [User Link], COUNT(*) as [NumBadges]
  FROM
    Users INNER JOIN Badges
    ON Users.Id = Badges.UserId
  GROUP BY
    Users.Id
    ORDER BY
  NumBadges DESC
```

Top 5 persons for maximum number of badges:

- Jon Skeet - 4968
- Marc Gravell - 1654
- Eric Lippert - 1206
- JaredPar - 1042
- Greg Hewgill - 968

Comment: I didn't got any clue for calculating other questions.